# Flutter swiper disable swipe when last index

Tags: flutter

I am using this plugin `flutter_swiper:`

```
Swiper(
        index: currentIndex,
        itemCount: 12,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return PhotoView(
            imageProvider: AssetImage("images/c"+(index+1).toString()+".jpg"),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I need the swiper to not swipe from last index to first index and not from first to last only swipe between indexes.
what I have is a list of images to swipe between 
**Is it possible to do this using this plugin or I should use another one ?**
if so please provide another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that [`Swiper`](https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper/blob/master/lib/src/swiper.dart) has a property for that, called `loop`:

> ```
> /// Set to false to disable continuous loop mode.
> final bool loop;
> ```

So you could try:

```
Swiper(
   loop: false,
   ...
```